# python soap client library

Tags: python, soap, pysimplesoap

There's a service in internet that i want to query with SOAP protocol. When searching for SOAP libraries for Python this post was informative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/206964. But none of libraries that i tried worked for this specific service. I have PHP script that works:

```
<?php

$client = new SoapClient('https://personyze.com/site/service/service/social_archive/', array('trace' => true));
$result = $client->__soapCall
(   'select', array
    (   array('server_id'=>123456, 'api_key'=>123456), 'user_id', null, null, false, 0, 1
    )
);
echo $client->__getLastRequestHeaders(), $client->__getLastRequest(), "RESULT:\n";
var_dump($result);
```

I have made the following attempts to do the same in Python:

1.

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client("https://personyze.com/site/service/service/social_archive/")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/client.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.wsdl = Definitions(url, options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/wsdl.py", line 194, in __init__
    self.build_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/wsdl.py", line 255, in build_schema
    self.schema = container.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 92, in load
    child.dereference()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/xsd/schema.py", line 295, in dereference
    midx, deps = x.dependencies()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/xsd/sxbasic.py", line 330, in dependencies
    raise TypeNotFound(self.ref)
suds.TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Array, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, )'
```

2.

```
from pysimplesoap.client import SoapClient
client = SoapClient(wsdl="https://personyze.com/site/service/service/social_archive/", trace=True)
client.select({"server_id":123456, "api_key":123456}, "user_id")
```

Much better! The best result for today. The only thing this library does wrong is that it calls method `selectRequest()` instead of `select()`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 140, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr,*args,**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 289, in wsdl_call
    response = self.call(method, *params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 188, in call
    raise SoapFault(unicode(response.faultcode), unicode(response.faultstring))
pysimplesoap.client.SoapFault: SOAP-ENV:Server: Procedure 'selectRequest' not present
```

3.

```
import SOAPpy
client = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy("https://personyze.com/site/service/service/social_archive/", "urn:SocialArchiveServiceProviderwsdl")
client.select({"server_id":123456, "api_key":123456}, "user_id", None, None, False, 0, 2)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 540, in __call__
    return self.__r_call(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 562, in __r_call
    self.__hd, self.__ma)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 464, in __call
    p, attrs = parseSOAPRPC(r, attrs = 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Parser.py", line 1074, in parseSOAPRPC
    t = _parseSOAP(xml_str, rules = rules)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Parser.py", line 1054, in _parseSOAP
    parser.parse(inpsrc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 107, in parse
    xmlreader.IncrementalParser.parse(self, source)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 123, in parse
    self.feed(buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 207, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 338, in start_element_ns
    AttributesNSImpl(newattrs, qnames))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SOAPpy-0.12.6-py2.7.egg/SOAPpy/Parser.py", line 109, in startElementNS
    "got `%s'" % toStr( name )
SOAPpy.Errors.Error: <Error : expected `SOAP-ENV:Envelope', got `wsdl:definitions'>
```

Please tell me what can i do to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server's WSDL schema seems to be broken - it references named objects without importing them.

See the [suds documentation on fixing broken schemas](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#FIXINGBROKENSCHEMAs) on how to work around that with suds.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719854/soap-suds-and-the-dreaded-schema-type-not-found-error) for more details.

This seems to work for me:

```
from suds.xsd.doctor import Import
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor
from suds.client import Client


url = 'https://personyze.com/site/service/service/social_archive/'
tns = 'urn:SocialArchiveServiceProviderwsdl'

imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add(tns)
client = Client(url,plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)])

print client.service.select({"server_id":123456, "api_key":123456}, "user_id")
```

Comment: The schema is really broken. This service uses YII Framework to generate schemas, which fails to generate valid schema when using arrays.