# python suds call magento api soap v1 Type Not Found Error

Tags: python, api, magento, soap, suds

Environment : CentOS 6.4 64bit, Python 2.6.6, Magento 1.7, Magento Core API, Suds 0.4.1

Python Code:

```
client = Client(http://   /figol/api/soap/?wsdl)
client.service.login('figol', 'figol123')
```

Error Detail:
TypeNotFound: Type not found: '(Array, http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/, )

But 
PHP Code:

```
$client = new SoapClient(http://    /figol/api/soap/?wsdl);
$session = $client->login('figol', 'figol123');
```

Works Perfectly.

I have tried many way([SOAP suds and the dreaded schema Type Not Found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719854/soap-suds-and-the-dreaded-schema-type-not-found-error)), but there is no luck.
Any help is very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how PHP works fine but I've encounter the same error when use suds in Python. This is due to broken wsdl/xsd. See [this post here](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/ticket/220).

Using suds's 'doctor' [module](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#Doctors) solves this issue.  Here is my code used to patch the broken wsdl definition I used to connect Magento api

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import

imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('urn:Magento')
d = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(self.url, doctor=d)
```