# suds error trying to load WSDL

Tags: python, soap, suds

I am trying to load a WSDL using the latest version of suds but getting the next error:

```
from suds.client import Client

//....
client = Client(url)

Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
```

I have tried using the Import and ImportDoctor functions as other threads say but I get the exactly the same result.

```
from suds.xsd.doctor import ImportDoctor, Import
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('https://www.soapservice.co.uk/test_ws')
doctor = ImportDoctor(imp)
client = Client(url, doctor=doctor)

Type not found: '(schema, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, )'
```

These are the WSDL definitions

```
<wsdl:definitions 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" 
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" 
xmlns:tns="https://www.soapservice.co.uk/test_ws" 
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" 
xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
targetNamespace="https://www.soapservice.co.uk/test_ws">
..............
..............
<wsdl:binding name="WebSoap" type="tns:WebSoap">
.............
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:binding name="WebSoap12" type="tns:WebSoap12">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
</wsdl:binding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessan explicit location or filter will help. E.g.:

```
imp = Import('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/', location='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/')
imp.filter.add('http://ws.client.com/Members.asmx')
client = Client(url,plugins=[ImportDoctor(imp)]
```

Comment: I get exactly the same error. I already tried that one as it was in another thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719854/soap-suds-and-the-dreaded-schema-type-not-found-error